# Old values not appearing in text field when called

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to call the old values to be edited. What part am I wrong at?

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
        $id = $_GET['edit'];
        $update = true;
        $record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM bookinfo WHERE BookNo='$BookNo'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($record) == 1 ) {
            $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
            $BookNo = $n['BookNo'];
            $ISBN = $n['ISBN'];
            $title = $n['title'];
            $author = $n['author'];
            $publisher = $n['publisher'];
            $status = $n['status'];
            $cost = $n['cost'];
        }
    }
?>
                <a href="viewBook.php?edit=<?php echo $row['BookNo']; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Edit</a>
            </td>



<?php
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) { ?>
<form method="post" action = "viewBook.php">
<input type="hidden" name="BookNo" value="<?php echo $BookNo; ?>">
<input type="text" name="ISBN" value="<?php echo $ISBN; ?>">
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
<input type="text" name="author" value="<?php echo $author; ?>">
<input type="text" name="publisher" value="<?php echo $publisher; ?>">
<input type="text" name="status" value="<?php echo $status; ?>">
<input type="text" name="cost" value="<?php echo $cost; ?>">
<?php if ($update == true): ?>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="update" style="background: #556B2F;" >update</button>
<?php else: ?>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="save" >Save</button>
<?php endif ?>
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

So far, what it does is, when the user clicks the edit button, it just shows 6 text fields. I thought by doing what I did, it was supposed to show the details already filled in the textbox.

Comment: where is `$BookNo` defined in your query?

Comment: It is defined in a separate file, called server.php and it's included at the top. It is defined as `$BookNo = "";`

Comment: and where do you assign the value to this variable?

Comment: At the top of the code that I posted, `$BookNo = $n['BookNo'];`

Comment: this happens AFTER the query runs. But you are using this variable in the query BEFORE the variable gets a value. Do you see your error now?

Comment: @LelioFaieta ahh okay that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
$record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM bookinfo WHERE BookNo='$BookNo'");
```

$BookNo is not defined.

maybe you wanted to do something like this:

```
$id = $_GET['edit'];
$update = true;
$record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM bookinfo WHERE BookNo='$id'");
```

Comment: Oh my... It was such a simple mistake. So sorry to have troubled you, but thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action = "viewBook.php">
```

your form method is "post" but you are checking $_GET You must check $_POST

```
if (isset($_GET['edit']))
```

Comment: It didn't affect it. I think it's also because the form method POST is for another form, and it's getting `<a href="viewBook.php?edit=<?php echo $row['BookNo']; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Edit</a>`

Comment: I posted a first answer, wich was bad, and you noticed it.
In fact, I deleted it quite instantly, modified it to the validated answer, and undeleted it. And my first answer is still there, and you commented it...
I am new to stackoverflow, and I don't understand everything...
I can not delete this answer any more :/

Answer (score 0):

you are passing value in `$id` And using `$BookNo` which not define.

only 6 input field will be show because first one is using hidden property.

```
<input type="hidden" name="BookNo" value="<?php echo $BookNo; ?>">
```

when you click on submit button data will be receive by $_POST